# When mapping Entity to Dto inside @Query in Hibernate 5 it throwing error Count query validation failed for method

Tags: java, hibernate, spring-boot, spring-data-jpa

I am using Hibernate in my Spring Boot application. Earlier I was using Spring Boot 1.2 and now I updated to latest 2.9. After updating it started throwing error **Count query validation failed for method public abstract org.springframework.data.domain.Page** when mapping Entity to Dto in the @Query.

Here is the code:

```
@Query("SELECT  new com.dto.UserDto(u) from UserEntity u")
public Page<UserDto> getUsers(Pageable page);
```

After updating it started throwing exception when initializing the bean.

Error:

```
org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'userRepositery': nested exception is java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Count query validation failed for method public abstract org.springframework.data.domain.Page com.repos.UserRepositery.getUsers(org.springframework.data.domain.Pageable)!
at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor$AutowiredFieldElement.inject(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:598) ~[spring-beans-5.1.10.RELEASE.jar:5.1.10.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.InjectionMetadata.inject(InjectionMetadata.java:90) ~[spring-beans-5.1.10.RELEASE.jar:5.1.10.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.postProcessProperties(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:376) ~[spring-beans-5.1.10.RELEASE.jar:5.1.10.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.populateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1411) ~[spring-beans-5.1.10.RELEASE.jar:5.1.10.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:592) ~[spring-beans-5.1.10.RELEASE.jar:5.1.10.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:515) ~[spring-beans-5.1.10.RELEASE.jar:5.1.10.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.lambda$doGetBean$0(AbstractBeanFactory.java:320) ~[spring-beans-5.1.10.RELEASE.jar:5.1.10.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:222) ~[spring-beans-5.1.10.RELEASE.jar:5.1.10.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:318) ~[spring-beans-5.1.10.RELEASE.jar:5.1.10.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:199) ~[spring-beans-5.1.10.RELEASE.jar:5.1.10.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.preInstantiateSingletons(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:847) ~[spring-beans-5.1.10.RELEASE.jar:5.1.10.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:877) ~[spring-context-5.1.10.RELEASE.jar:5.1.10.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:549) ~[spring-context-5.1.10.RELEASE.jar:5.1.10.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.context.ServletWebServerApplicationContext.refresh(ServletWebServerApplicationContext.java:141) ~[spring-boot-2.1.9.RELEASE.jar:2.1.9.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh(SpringApplication.java:744) [spring-boot-2.1.9.RELEASE.jar:2.1.9.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refreshContext(SpringApplication.java:391) [spring-boot-2.1.9.RELEASE.jar:2.1.9.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:312) [spring-boot-2.1.9.RELEASE.jar:2.1.9.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1215) [spring-boot-2.1.9.RELEASE.jar:2.1.9.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1204) [spring-boot-2.1.9.RELEASE.jar:2.1.9.RELEASE]
at com.afcs.AfcsApplication.main(AfcsApplication.java:29) [classes/:na]
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) ~[na:1.8.0_222]
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62) ~[na:1.8.0_222]
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) ~[na:1.8.0_222]
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498) ~[na:1.8.0_222]
at org.springframework.boot.devtools.restart.RestartLauncher.run(RestartLauncher.java:49) [spring-boot-devtools-2.1.9.RELEASE.jar:2.1.9.RELEASE]
```

I can map User Entity to Dto in Service class, but in application there is lot of implement ions like so I can't change all of them.

How can I fix it or any alternate way ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Could you try updating with custom countQuery attribute-

```
import org.springframework.data.domain.Page;
import org.springframework.data.domain.Pageable;
import org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.JpaRepository;
import org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.Query;


     @Query(value = "SELECT  new com.dto.UserDto(u) FROM com.entity.UserEntity AS u",
       countQuery = "SELECT count(u) FROM com.entity.UserEntity AS u")
      public Page<UserDto> getUsers(Pageable page);
```

Dependencies used:

```
<parent>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
    <version>2.1.7.RELEASE</version>
    <relativePath /> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
</parent>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.h2database</groupId>
        <artifactId>h2</artifactId>
        <scope>runtime</scope>
    </dependency>
```

Comment: Let me know if you are getting any exception, I have tested the code with - Spring Boot version: <version>2.1.7.RELEASE</version>

Comment: It is working fine but why not the count query generated by hibernate working. Here the hibernate query "select count(new com.dto.UserDto(u))FROM com.entity.UserEntity AS u"

Comment: That is sure the syntax is not supported when Spring auto creates the countQuery for the Select query. I'll get back with more details.

Comment: When you use Page<?> it has to count the number of records present in the DB to support pagination. So is the case with the requirement. The query auto-generated by the framework doesn't have appropriate semantics as shared by you. The reason to fail and log an exception - QuerySyntaxException: unexpected token: count near line 1

Comment: @Jatish Great explanation about `countQuery`, thanks. It solved my problem.